# how to send Multipart.Part in intent

Tags: android, okhttp, multipart

I've a **okhttp3.MultipartBody.Part** in an activity and need to send that to next activity through Intent put extra.

It gives me an error

> Parcel: unable to marshal value okhttp3.MultipartBody$Part

As a work around, I've added a static variable in util file and accessing it in next activity.

Is there a possibility to send it in intent?
Is it stopping because it's a huge data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to send it in intent?

No, sorry.

> Is it stopping because it's a huge data?

No. It is stopping because it is the wrong data type. `Intent` extras cannot hold arbitrary objects.

It is also possible that it would crash your app due to size, depending on what is in it, but you are not even getting that far.

> As a work around, I've added a static variable in util file and accessing it in next activity.

In modern Android apps, ideally neither activity would have any OkHttp objects. Have a repository handle your communications with the server, and the activities (or, better yet, viewmodels for those activities) can talk to the repository. See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide for more.

Comment: Wow. I got an answer from @CommonsWare. That's an achievement for me :) #massiveRespect

Comment: Okay. I'm trying to send an audio, a file and an image in retrofit API call. For that I'm using an ArrayList<Multipart.Part> which has these 3 files. That's the requirement

Comment: @Prabs: That's fine. But, ideally, the Retrofit call is not being made by either activity directly. Something else handles that (a repository). Such a repository usually is a singleton (whether created by hand or managed by a dependency inversion framework like Dagger or Koin), and so both activities can talk to it. Then, you are not passing the OkHttp objects between activities. Think of it as being like your static variable approach, but super-charged. :-) Also, thanks for the kind words!

Comment: @Prabs: [This Java app module](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/-/tree/v0.8/Weather) and [its Kotlin counterpart](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v0.8/Weather) demonstrate this technique.